# How to interact with browser in VB.NET

Tags: javascript, php, vb.net, web, vb.net-2010

I have three website links:

**link1.domain.com**

**link2.domain.com**

**link3.domain.com**

And Three VB.NET Applications:

**App1** for **link1.domain.com**

**App2** for **link2.domain.com**

**App3** for **link3.domain.com**

I want something like whenever I run App1 **ONLY link1.domain.com** will be available to access, and **link2** *&* **link3** will be hidden and not accessable and so on...

I also want my website unreachable when someone tries to access it without the app.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use a webbrowser control inside each application. The following link shows how to restrict urls in the webbrowser.

[How can I prevent a user from browsing to certain web sites in a WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139459/how-can-i-prevent-a-user-from-browsing-to-certain-web-sites-in-a-webbrowser-cont)

For the 'must use app' restriction you can do this by making your app automatically login to the website that it has permission for and denying all anonymous users.

Example of auto login is here: [C# - Automatic Login to a webpage using WebBrowser - disabled html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585355/c-sharp-automatic-login-to-a-webpage-using-webbrowser-disabled-html-tag)

Comment: I do not want to use WebBrowser control, I want my application to interact with (e.g Chrome, Firefox, IE etc).